# domain service calling from domain entity

Tags: domain-driven-design

Can a domain service can be call from domain entity, through service interface.

For eg- :

employee.Fire() calling IEmployee firing service. I am calling through Interface not through concrete one.

Is that possible ?

Comment: What is possible? Using the interface reference? Calling through a service? Are you asking if this is correct DDD? Your question is not clear. Please clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can do that without any complilation error, but I don't think it's a good idea to call domain service in a domain entity.

Normally if the action affects more than one entities, we will put the logic in the service method. So if the fire action affects only current employee, should encapsulate inside employee.Fire(). Else if affects multi employees, should put in service and application should invoke service.Fire() instead of employee.File()